# Convert daily data to quarterly data and convert back after forecasting

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

My idea is about forecasting data with different time period :

For example :

```
                 A     day  month   year  quarter   week    
Date                                
2016-01-04     36.81    4        1      2016    1      1           
2016-01-05     35.97    5        1      2016    1      1           
2016-01-06     33.97    6        1      2016    1      1           
2016-01-07     33.29    7        1      2016    1      1           
2016-01-08     33.20    8        1      2016    1      2           
2016-01-11     31.42    11       1      2016    1      2          
2016-01-12     30.42    12       1      2016    1      2
```

I have daily data and i wanted to forecast data in month and again convert month back to daily.

The method I used is getting percentage of each day and month from it's sum

Here are some code i used:

```
 converted_data = data.groupby( [data['month'], data['day']] )['A'].sum()
 average = converted_data/converted_data.sum()
 average
```

which give the following result:

```
month  day         A
 1      3      0.002218
        4      0.003815
        5      0.003801
          ...
 12     26     0.002522
        27     0.004764
        28     0.004822
        29     0.004839
        30     0.002277
```

By using this when i want to convert back from yearly data to daily i just multipling the average by result of the forecast

But this does not work when i wanted to convert **daily data** to **quarterly data**.

Can anyone suggested any idea on how to do it.

Thank you for your consideration.

## Edit

the data i want is the percentage of the data in day restective to quarter

something like:

```
A = total when day is equal to 1 in data and also for day 2 and 3...

#for example my data is
Date      value
1/1/2000  50
1/2/2000  50
1/3/2000  40

than A of day 1 is 140

B = total when quarter is equal to 1 in data and and also for quarter 2 and 3 4
#for example my data is
Date      value
1/1/2000   4000 #-->quarter 1
1/4/2000   5000 #-->quarter 2
1/7/2000   2000 #-->quarter 3
1/10/2000  1000 #-->quarter 4
1/1/20001  2000 #-->quarter 1


than average of day 1 respective quarter is 140/6000 as a is in quarter one
```

The data above is what I converted.

First, I am receiving and input data as daily and I converted from pandas series to dataframe shown above the column, day, month, year, quarter, week was extracted in order to group the data my method work well for converting to year and month.

The reason why I do these because when my input is given in daily and I wanted to convert to year in order to do forecasting.

After the forecasting i will be getting the forecast value in yearly form so i wanted to convert it back to daily and the method i did is to find the portion of previous data.

I am so sorry, for the unclear question.
Again thank for your help.

Comment: A little confusing with conversion. Can you update what is the expected answer? you have month, year, and quarter column. what are you trying to "convert back"?

Comment: @GravityMass i have year month quarter in order to group and i edited the question i hope you can understand,thank you.